# SSSD Integration with Microsoft AD for SSH Key based Login

Tags: active-directory, centos7, sssd

I have configured SSSD on a linux machine which is connected to a Microsoft AD Forest using Realm.

My End Goal is to Login into CentOS machine using the SSH keys stored in Microsoft AD

Below are Setup Details:

- EC2 Windows for Microsoft AD
- EC2 Amazon Linux with SSSD Configured

I am able to login into the linux machine using the AD Username and Password.

I have now stored the SSH Public keys in the Microsoft AD **altSecurityIdentities** user attributes as well as **sshPublicKeys** attribute.

Below are the Config file for SSSD

```
[sssd]
domains = test.com
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam, ssh, sudo
debug_level=10

[domain/test.com]
ad_domain = test.com
ad_server = test.com
krb5_realm = TEST.COM
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-samba 
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = False
fallback_homedir = /home/%u
access_provider = ad
#SSH KEY FETCH
ldap_user_extra_attrs = altSecurityIdentities:altSecurityIdentities
ldap_user_ssh_public_key = altSecurityIdentities
ldap_use_tokengroups = True

[nss]
debug_level=10
```

I am getting below error in the sssd_nsss logs

```
[sssd[nss]] [cache_req_search_send] (0x0400): CR #476: Object found, but needs to be refreshed.
[sssd[nss]] [cache_req_search_dp] (0x0400): CR #476: Looking up [demo_user@test.com] in data provider
[sssd[nss]] [sss_dp_issue_request] (0x0400): Issuing request for [0x55bf7f9683e0:3:demo_user@test.com@test.com]
[sssd[nss]] [sss_dp_get_account_msg] (0x0400): Creating request for [test.com][0x3][BE_REQ_INITGROUPS][name=demo_user@test.com:-]
[sssd[nss]] [sbus_add_timeout] (0x2000): 0x55bf80d3c120
[sssd[nss]] [sss_dp_internal_get_send] (0x0400): Entering request [0x55bf7f9683e0:3:demo_user@test.com@test.com]
[sssd[nss]] [sbus_remove_timeout] (0x2000): 0x55bf80d3c120
[sssd[nss]] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): dbus conn: 0x55bf80d27fe0
[sssd[nss]] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): Dispatching.
[sssd[nss]] [sss_dp_get_reply] (0x0010): The Data Provider returned an error [org.freedesktop.sssd.Error.DataProvider.Offline]
[sssd[nss]] [cache_req_common_dp_recv] (0x0040): CR #476: Data Provider Error: 3, 5, Failed to get reply from Data Provider
[sssd[nss]] [cache_req_common_dp_recv] (0x0400): CR #476: Due to an error we will return cached data
[sssd[nss]] [cache_req_search_cache] (0x0400): CR #476: Looking up [demo_user@test.com] in cache
[sssd[nss]] [ldb] (0x4000): Added timed event "ldb_kv_callback": 0x55bf80d3bc90

[sssd[nss]] [ldb] (0x4000): Added timed event "ldb_kv_timeout": 0x55bf80d2bb90
[sssd[nss]] [ldb] (0x4000): Running timer event 0x55bf80d3bc90 "ldb_kv_callback"
[sssd[nss]] [ldb] (0x4000): Destroying timer event 0x55bf80d2bb90 "ldb_kv_timeout"
[sssd[nss]] [ldb] (0x4000): Destroying timer event 0x55bf80d3bc90 "ldb_kv_callback"
[sssd[nss]] [ldb] (0x4000): Added timed event "ldb_kv_callback": 0x55bf80d3bc90
[sssd[nss]] [ldb] (0x4000): Added timed event "ldb_kv_timeout": 0x55bf80d2bb90
[sssd[nss]] [ldb] (0x4000): Running timer event 0x55bf80d3bc90 "ldb_kv_callback"
[sssd[nss]] [ldb] (0x4000): Destroying timer event 0x55bf80d2bb90 "ldb_kv_timeout"
[sssd[nss]] [ldb] (0x4000): Destroying timer event 0x55bf80d3bc90 "ldb_kv_callback"
[sssd[nss]] [ldb] (0x4000): Added timed event "ldb_kv_callback": 0x55bf80d43d00
[sssd[nss]] [ldb] (0x4000): Added timed event "ldb_kv_timeout": 0x55bf80d41100
[sssd[nss]] [ldb] (0x4000): Running timer event 0x55bf80d43d00 "ldb_kv_callback"
[sssd[nss]] [ldb] (0x4000): Added timed event "ldb_kv_callback": 0x55bf80d46b00
[sssd[nss]] [ldb] (0x4000): Added timed event "ldb_kv_timeout": 0x55bf80d46bd0
[sssd[nss]] [ldb] (0x4000): Destroying timer event 0x55bf80d41100 "ldb_kv_timeout"
[sssd[nss]] [ldb] (0x4000): Destroying timer event 0x55bf80d43d00 "ldb_kv_callback"
[sssd[nss]] [ldb] (0x4000): Running timer event 0x55bf80d46b00 "ldb_kv_callback"
[sssd[nss]] [ldb] (0x4000): Destroying timer event 0x55bf80d46bd0 "ldb_kv_timeout"
[sssd[nss]] [ldb] (0x4000): Destroying timer event 0x55bf80d46b00 "ldb_kv_callback"

[sssd[nss]] [cache_req_search_ncache_filter] (0x0400): CR #476: This request type does not support filtering result by negative cache
[sssd[nss]] [cache_req_search_done] (0x0400): CR #476: Returning updated object [demo_user@test.com]
[sssd[nss]] [cache_req_create_and_add_result] (0x0400): CR #476: Found 2 entries in domain test.com
[sssd[nss]] [sss_dp_req_destructor] (0x0400): Deleting request: [0x55bf7f9683e0:3:demo_user@test.com@test.com]
[sssd[nss]] [cache_req_done] (0x0400): CR #476: Finished: Success
[sssd[nss]] [nss_protocol_done] (0x4000): Sending reply: success
```

The SSSD_SSH logs are below

```
[sssd[ssh]] [sss_dp_get_reply] (0x0010): The Data Provider returned an error [org.freedesktop.sssd.Error.DataProvider.Offline]
[sssd[ssh]] [sss_dp_get_reply] (0x0010): The Data Provider returned an error [org.freedesktop.sssd.Error.DataProvider.Offline]
[sssd[ssh]] [sss_dp_get_reply] (0x0010): The Data Provider returned an error [org.freedesktop.sssd.Error.DataProvider.Offline]
[sssd[ssh]] [sss_dp_get_reply] (0x0010): The Data Provider returned an error [org.freedesktop.sssd.Error.DataProvider.Offline]
[sssd[ssh]] [sss_dp_get_reply] (0x0010): The Data Provider returned an error [org.freedesktop.sssd.Error.DataProvider.Offline]
[sssd[ssh]] [sss_dp_get_reply] (0x0010): The Data Provider returned an error [org.freedesktop.sssd.Error.DataProvider.Offline]
[sssd[ssh]] [sss_dp_get_reply] (0x0010): The Data Provider returned an error [org.freedesktop.sssd.Error.DataProvider.Offline]
[sssd[ssh]] [sss_dp_get_reply] (0x0010): The Data Provider returned an error [org.freedesktop.sssd.Error.DataProvider.Offline]
[sssd[ssh]] [sss_dp_get_reply] (0x0010): The Data Provider returned an error [org.freedesktop.sssd.Error.DataProvider.Offline]
[sssd[ssh]] [sss_dp_get_reply] (0x0010): The Data Provider returned an error [org.freedesktop.sssd.Error.DataProvider.Offline]
```

When I try to login using ssh using the below command

```
ssh demo_user@test.com@<IP>
```

I get the below error

```
demo_user@test.com@<IP>: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

I have tried below things

- Dig
  [image]
- id demo_user@test.com

  uid=1277801117(demo_user) gid=1277800513(domain users) groups=1277800513(domain users)

I have tried restarting the SSSD Demon but it did not help as suggested in few forums

Is there a way I can make this work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[sssd[nss]] [sss_dp_get_reply] (0x0010): The Data Provider returned an error [org.freedesktop.sssd.Error.DataProvider.Offline]
[sssd[nss]] [cache_req_common_dp_recv] (0x0040): CR #476: Data Provider Error: 3, 5, Failed to get reply from Data Provider
[sssd[nss]] [cache_req_common_dp_recv] (0x0400): CR #476: Due to an error we will return cached data
```

This tells you that the data provider is offline and the output you see with the `id` command is coming from the cache. Please check the SSSD domain log (sssd_*.test.com.log) why the client can't talk to the backend.

Once this is fixed, please verify your `ssh_config` is setup correctly to fetch the public key from AD. The following options need to be in this file:

```
AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/bin/sss_ssh_authorizedkeys
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser root
```

You can verify that the ssh key proxy works as expected by running the tool manually:

```
# sss_ssh_authorizedkeys demo_user
```

But again, this will not work until the SSSD data provider can successfully talk to the AD backend.

Comment: Please refer to the question below

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64026565/resolve-ad-domain-using-etc-resolv-conf-in-centos

I have to figure out a way to resolve multiple domains in the resolv.conf file