# Resolve AD Domain using /etc/resolv.conf in CentOS

Tags: dns, centos, resolv

I have configured SSSD using Realm to login into the centOS VM using the AD Credentials. Please refer the setup [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63705156/sssd-integration-with-microsoft-ad-for-ssh-key-based-login)

I had to modify the **/etc/resolv.conf** file to point the namserver to the AD Domain

Original **/etc/resolv.conf** file:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search ap-south-1.compute.internal
nameserver 172.31.0.2
```

Updated **/etc/resolv.conf** file:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search test.com
nameserver 172.31.12.38
```

With the updated **/etc/resolv.conf** file the User is able to login using AD Credentials but the original domain is not resolved

I want a way to resolve both the domains that point to different nameservers

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 172.31.0.2
nameserver 172.31.12.38
search ap-south-1.compute.internal test.com
```

I have tried multiple ways to resolve the domains using the deprecated tags as well

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
domain ap-south-1.compute.internal
nameserver 172.31.0.2

domain test.com
nameserver 172.31.12.38
```

I have even tried the rotate option

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
options rotate
options timeout:1
nameserver 172.31.0.2
nameserver 172.31.12.38
search ap-south-1.compute.internal test.com
```

Is there a way to resolve multiple domains that point to different nameservers using the **/etc/resolv.conf**

Comment: I think what you are looking for is [DNS delegation](https://serverfault.com/a/530518/561297).

Comment: Another, less recommended option, would be to configure your local DNS with forward zones. An example for the BIND DNS server is given here: https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/v9_16_6/reference.html?highlight=forward%20zone#zone-types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resolve the AD Forest Domain we can configure the ad_server parameter in the **sssd.conf** file

ref link: [man_page_sssd](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sssd-ad) [Refer the ad_server part]

**/etc/sssd/sssd.conf** file for reference:

Original File:

```
[sssd]
domains = test.com
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam, sudo, ssh

[nss]
debug_level = 10

[domain/test.com]
ad_domain = test.com
krb5_realm = TEST.COM
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli 
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = False
fallback_homedir = /home/%u
access_provider = simple
ldap_user_extra_attrs = altSecurityIdentities:altSecurityIdentities
ldap_user_ssh_public_key = altSecurityIdentities
ldap_use_tokengroups = True
```

Updated File:

```
[sssd]
domains = test.com
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam, sudo, ssh

[nss]
debug_level = 10

[domain/test.com]
ad_domain = test.com
ad_server = 172.31.12.38, 172.31.12.48
krb5_realm = TEST.COM
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli 
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = False
fallback_homedir = /home/%u
access_provider = simple
ldap_user_extra_attrs = altSecurityIdentities:altSecurityIdentities
ldap_user_ssh_public_key = altSecurityIdentities
ldap_use_tokengroups = True
```

This way we can avoid making any entries in the **/etc/resolv.conf** file